# How to associate marks for each answer button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I have a piece of code below where it displays a list of possible answers for each question displayed as checkbox buttons. What I want to do is associate marks for each answer button which can be retrieved from the db. For correct answers retrieve their marks from db. For incorrect answers their marks are each worth 0. My question is how and what is best way to do this:

DB TABLES:

**Question:**

```
QuestionId (PK auto)  QuestionNo  SessionId (FK Session) OptionId (FK Option)    
72                    1           26                     3
73                    2           26                     4
```

**Option_Table:**

```
OptionId (PK Auto)  OptionType
1                   A-C
2                   A-D
3                   A-E
4                   A-F
```

**Answer:**

```
AnswerId (PK auto)    QuestionId (FK Question)      Answer  
1                          72                         C             
2                          73                         A             
3                          73                         C             
4                          73                         D
```

**Individual_Answer:**

```
AnswerId (PK auto)  AnswerMarks
1                   2
2                   2
3                   1
4                   2
```

Code below where it compiles the query and comiples the answer buttons for each question:

```
    $qandaquery = "SELECT q.QuestionId, q.QuestionNo, o.OptionType, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT Answer
                    ORDER BY Answer
                    SEPARATOR ',' ) AS Answer
                    FROM Question q
                    LEFT JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionId = an.QuestionId
                    LEFT JOIN Individual_Answer ia ON an.AnswerId = ia.AnswerId
                    LEFT JOIN Option_Table o ON q.OptionId = o.OptionId
                    ";

    global $mysqli;
    $qandaqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($qandaquery);
    // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
    $qandaqrystmt->execute(); 
    $qandaqrystmt->bind_result($qandaQuestionId,$qandaQuestionNo,$qandaOptionType,$qandaAnswer);

    $arrQuestionId = array();
    $arrQuestionNo = array();
    $arrOptionType = array();
    $arrAnswer = array();
    $arrReplyType = array();

foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {

?>

<div class="queWrap">

//LOOP THROUGH EACH QUESTION
<p><?php echo "<strong>".htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionNo[$key])."</strong>"; ?></p>

//BELOW DISPLAYS THE ANSWER BUTTONS FOR EACH QUESTION
$options = explode('-', $arrOptionType[$key]);
if(count($options) > 1) {
    $start = array_shift($options);
    $end = array_shift($options);
    do {
        $options[] = $start;
    }while(++$start <= $end);
 }
 else{
    $options = explode(' or ', $option);
 }

       foreach($options as $indivOption) {
     echo '<div class="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="options_<?php echo $key; ?>[]" id="option-' . $indivOption . '" value="' . $indivOption . '" /><span>' . $indivOption . '</span></label></div>';
 }
?>

//HIDDEN INPUT SHOWING DB's QUESTIONID FOR EACH QUESTION
<p><input type='hidden' class='questionIds' name='questionids' value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionId[$key]); ?>' /></p>

</div>


<?php

}

?>
```

Below is Source Code which displays 2 questions and their answers:

```
    <div class="queWrap">

    //QUESTION 1

    <p><strong>1:</strong></p>

    //ANSWER BUTTONS FOR QUESTION 1

    <div class="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="options_<?php echo $key; ?>[]" id="option-A" value="A" /><span>A</span></label></div>
<div class="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="options_<?php echo $key; ?>[]" id="option-B" value="B" /><span>B</span></label></div>
<div class="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="options_<?php echo $key; ?>[]" id="option-C" value="C" /><span>C</span></label></div>
<div class="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="options_<?php echo $key; ?>[]" id="option-D" value="D" /><span>D</span></label></div>
<div class="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="options_<?php echo $key; ?>[]" id="option-E" value="E" /><span>E</span></label></div>

    //QUESTIONID FOR QUESTION 1

    <p><input type='text' class='questionIds' name='questionids' value='72' /></p>

    </div>

    <div class="queWrap">

    //QUESTION 2

    <p><strong>2:</strong></p>

    //ANSWER BUTTONS FOR QUESTION 2

    <div class="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="options_<?php echo $key; ?>[]" id="option-A" value="A" /><span>A</span></label></div>
<div class="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="options_<?php echo $key; ?>[]" id="option-B" value="B" /><span>B</span></label></div>
<div class="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="options_<?php echo $key; ?>[]" id="option-C" value="C" /><span>C</span></label></div>
<div class="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="options_<?php echo $key; ?>[]" id="option-D" value="D" /><span>D</span></label></div>
<div class="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="options_<?php echo $key; ?>[]" id="option-E" value="E" /><span>E</span></label></div>
<div class="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="options_<?php echo $key; ?>[]" id="option-F" value="F" /><span>F</span></label></div>

    //QUESTIONID FOR QUESTION 2

    <p><input type='text' class='questionIds' name='questionids' value='73' /></p>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an AJAX request to server every time a checkbox is selected. This allows you to keep all answers on server and monitor progress there.

First I would add a `data-` attribute to question wrapper rather than using an extra input to store question ID:

```
<div class="queWrap" data-q_id="72">
```

jQuery:

```
$function(){
    $('.queWrap input:checkbox').change(function() {
        var $ch_box = $(this),
            $qwrap=$ch_box.closest('.queWrap')
            q_id = $qwrap.data('q_id'),
            val = $ch_box.val();

        var dataToServer = {
            q_id: q_id,
            valueSelected: val
        }

        /* due to demo environment sending dummy data*/

        $.post('/echo/json/', dataToServer, function (response) {
            /* disable checkboxes for this question- would need to track at server that user only submits once for each question*/
            $qwrap.find('input:checkbox').prop('disabled',true);
             /* demo uses JSON response {"status":"correct"}*/
            var status=response.status
            $qwrap.find('.status').text( status).addClass(status);
        });    
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/bWthd/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, can I ask a question, in your code obviously you have written it so that it fetermines if the answer selected is correct or not and disabled the checkboxes, obviously I removed the line of code which disabled the buttons, what my question is how to implement it so that it counts the marks for each answer selected. All incorrect answers are `0` and correct answers marks  depends on answer selected. This is so then hidden is the total of marks for each question determined from the answers selected.

Comment: numerous ways to do it... store mark value in data of each question, or send with response data. Keep a counter going in page and update counter within success callback of each ajax call

Comment: I know I am asking a lot but can you show a code snippet for this in your own time, you have more knowledge into doing this as I have hardly used ajax and I need to get this completed asap. I am not a strong web programmer, I deal more with oracle/sql and some php and only have basic web programming knowledge such as HTML, CSS, javascript etc. I know I am asking a lot but really aprreciate it if you can do this for me